# Moving Android/Eclipse project to new PC

Tags: android, eclipse

Well, I hosed up my Android development PC, but didn't care all that much since I really needed a newer, much faster PC for this work. And here I am now with a high-end Windows 7 64-bit box.

Eclipse and all the Android components are up and running, but the one thing I'm having trouble with is how to get my previous project into the new workspace. I copied over my entire old workspace directory from the old disk and made that my Eclipse workspace, but it doesn't automatically see the projects that are there. I tried creating a new Android project "from existing source", but it complained about having "overlapping projects" or some such.

Is there a way to have it recognize the existing project files, or should I move them somewhere else, create the project from scratch, and then copy the old files back into the project tree? Or any other solutions?

Comment: Did you copy your `.metadata` folder?

Comment: You may want to consider using a source control system to manage your code to prevent this problem from happening again in the future (use SVN or GIT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was one other complication. On my "old" PC I had been using Eclipse Helios, which apparently has some minor compatibility issues with ADT, so on my new PC I went with Galileo instead, and there might be some differences in existing files in the project directory.

In any case, what I did was to move my old project directory to a temp location, create a new project in Eclipse with the same name and basic settings, close Eclipse, copy my whole directory tree back into the new project directories, and then restart Eclipse. Eclipse bitched a bit about something, then went ahead and rebuilt everything.

I'm back in business! Thanks for all the responses.

BTW, the entire install process took a long time since I wasn't sure whether to install 64-bit Java or 32-bit (32-bit was required), etc. But it's nice to be running on a clean, fast PC instead of one that's been accumulating general crud for several years.

Answer (score 10):

A super easy way is by just doing an Import.

1. Select File Import.
2. Select Existing Projects Into Workspace and click next.
3. Select the directory of the project file.
4. Click Finish.

You will have to do this for each project.  Note, that you may need to remove the project folder that you copied into the workspace manually, because this procedure will automatically copy the folder and hierarchy for you.

Answer (score 1):

I used this method to code on my home machine as well as a development environment running from a live CD while attending classes in the computer lab.

1. Get [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).
2. Put your workspace in a Dropbox folder.
3. Point the new machine's Eclipse install to your
   Dropbox workspace folder after it
   has updated itself.
4. Get back to coding.

Hope this works for you.  It did for me.

Comment: I have some difficulties using a similar approach in this question `http://stackoverflow.com/q/9559932/410975`. The problem is that files which don't match on each system get copied over. So when Dropbox/SpiderOak/etc copy things over they shouldn't copy over files which only Eclipse on the local system should handle. So some sort of export and import seems necessary. The workspace folder has class paths and other files which can create faulty dependencies. How can this be accounted for?

Comment: I should add that this approach was used with two Ubuntu machines.  I am not certain if it would work across different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Move each of the projects in your hard disk to the new PC's workspace, or wherever you want to have them. Do not copy the metadata folder!. Then create new projects from existing sources (yes, you'll have to manually do this for each of the projects)

Ger

Comment: This is wrong.  It will generate an error, saying the project already exists in the workspace, since you moved the folder with the same name into your new workspace folder.

Comment: @ggomeze, is omitting the metadata folder enough? What about potential path inconsistencies brought about when other files are copied? can you relate this to my question `http://stackoverflow.com/q/9559932/410975`?

Comment: metadata?. Where is that folder located?. Maybe that's a specific folder on Windows (i'm working on Mac OS). If it is, then i'm answering your question, as you will not need that folder in your linux based environment. As a rule of thumb, do not transfer any file related to Eclipse, or built files. As someone already suggested, using a repository (cvs, svn, git, mercurial, etc) is a good practice even if you work alone.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old question but it is a issue I ran into when moving my project over from my home theater PC  to my new laptop so I can leave my HTPC to doing HTPC things. Anyways what I did was I imported my project from over the computer over the network to my new laptop using new android project from existing code. The files where populated but it changed my root folder name. Being OCD I wanted to change the name of the root folder back to what I had on the other machine. I found if I right clicked the item in the project tree and selected refactor I could rename it back to what it was on my HTPC. This then resulted in my laptop having a exact working copy of the code so I can program from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy whole Workspace just through **import>General>Existing Projects into Workspace>Select root Directory>finish**

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the export/import eclipse mechanim works fine with 2 linked projects: android and app engine?