# Is there a way to move an Android project from one workspace to another

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to move an Android project from one work space to another?

My hard drive crashed and I had to re-install everything, now when I open the old workspaces, eclipse cannot find any of the imports.

Answer (score 0):

I moved projects several times succesfully.
On re-installing, did you defined the workspace to directory that contains old projects?
Did you tried to import manually?
And finally, try those [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167335/moving-android-eclipse-project-to-new-pc?rq=1)